# Building APIs using Laravel returns empty object only when called via javascript ... sometimes

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, caching, axios

I'm building a webpage using VueJS and Laravel, everything worked fine until I hit this problem.

First, let me share the necessary code:

```
<script>
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'

    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        methods: {
            getHotelsByCityName: async function () {

                const resp = await axios.get('localhost/api/hotels');
                console.log(resp);
                
            }
        },
    })
</script>
```

The Javascript code for sending the request is really as simple as that, and then for the backend I just encode the data in JSON format and send it back to the client.

```
   public function getHotels(Amadeus $amadeus,$destination)
    {
        $hotels =   $amadeus->searchForHotelsByCityOrAirportName($destination);
        return response()->json($hotels);
    }
```

Please note that I sometimes get the data, and sometimes I get empty object , in fact , If I open the webpage and just keep on refreshing it , sometimes I get the data and sometimes I don't , I found that clearing browser cache increase the chance of me getting the right data so it could be a caching problem, but what is being cached exactly ? what's going on here?

I am using Amadeus APIs , and just so you know, when I visit the API link directly in the browser it always work. so the backend seems fine, not sure where the problem is.

**Edit 1:** I noticed that I'm getting an empty object (again sometimes) when I inspect the request using google chrome dev tools, but again when I hit the API with the browser directly everything works fine, I am not getting any errors in the console but I am guessing it could be a headers , or cookies problem. if someone could help I'd greatly appreciate it.

**Edit 2:** I found out that if i wait a couple of seconds and then execute the method everything works fine, the problem only happens when I call `getHotelsByCityName` from mounted() `function` or any other method that executes as soon as the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Press F12 or ctrl+shift+I to open the developers tools on your browser. And switch to `network` panel to check the requests sent by browser and the results sent by server.

I believe that `getHotelsByCityName()` should be written in `created` or `mounted` section in Vue to get the data when page is loaded.

Comment: I'll edit the question to include more details regarding that

Answer (score 0):

Use then for async await

```
<script>
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'

    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        methods: {
            getHotelsByCityName: async function () {

               await axios.get('localhost/api/hotels').then(resp => {
                  console.log(resp)
               })
                
            }
        },
    })
</script>
```

Comment: I've edited the question to add more details , async await is not the reason for my problem.

Comment: @Tarek, did you test your backend api with postman? if so, I do believe it async await issue.  You console the response before the data return. why somehow you data, but other somehow you won't

Comment: I tried it , same problem, first time I refreshed the page it worked , the second it didn't

Comment: did you check with status 200? Please your exactly code.

Comment: Yes I am getting 200 status code, I think the problem is that the async await is returning immediately when called from mount function in vuejs